# when i am creating rectangle and filling color in it then text entered is not visible

Tags: text, fonts, background-color

In the below code i want to create a rectangle and fill color in it,After that i want to enter the text in it but here when i fill the color the text entered is invisible.. 
<**

```
DrawRect(70,5,180,120,COLOR_FONT);      
FillRect(70,5,180,120,COLOR_FONT);
kbReset(); 
SetBackLight(temGetIdleTime()+5);  
dspClean(COLOR_BACKGROUND);
font = 24;
y = 0
y+= font;       
DrawText("HHHIIII",giWdt/2,20,0,0,TOP_CENTER, font,COLOR_FONT);         
y+= font;       
DrawText("AAAAAAA",giWdt/2,y,0,0,TOP_CENTER,font,COLOR_FONT);       
y+= font;       
DrawText("BBBBBBBB",giWdt/2,y,0,0,TOP_CENTER,font,COLOR_FONT);      
y+= font;       
DrawText("CCCCCC",giWdt/2,y,0,0,TOP_CENTER,font,COLOR_FONT);        
y+= font;
```

**>

Answer (score -1):

```
DrawRect (70,5,180,120,COLOR_FONT);

FillRect (70,5,180,120,COLOR_FONT);

kbReset (); 

SetBackLight (temGetIdleTime ()+5);  

dspClean (COLOR_BACKGROUND);

font = 24;

y = 0

y+= font;   

DrawText(" HHHIIII ", giWdt /2,20,0,0,TOP_CENTER, font,COLOR_Background); 

y+= font;     

DrawText (" AAAAAAA ", giWdt /2,y,0,0,TOP_CENTER,font,COLOR_Background); 

y+= font;     

DrawText (" BBBBBBBB ", giWdt /2,y,0,0,TOP_CENTER,font,COLOR_Background); 

y+= font;    

DrawText (" CCCCCC ", giWdt /2,y,0,0,TOP_CENTER,font,COLOR_Background);  

y+= font;
```